# Android - Memory Allocation Tracker not tracking my test allocation

Tags: android, memory-management, ddms

I'm currently playing around with the memory allocation tracker of the DDMS tool.
In my project i insert the following line in a button's `onClickListener`:

```
memTrackerTest = new byte[1024*1024];
```

`memTrackerTest` is a private variable of the Activity.

I would expect to see the allocation in the tracker but unfortunately it doesn't appear.
Other parts of my code, like the creation of a `ProgressDialog` show up fine.

Any idea why my big allocation is not displayed in the allocation tracker?

Comment: It should be there.  Every allocation is included, including some of the buffer manipulation used to package and send the allocations up to DDMS.

Comment: yeah i see those. but not my allocation :( it should be on the top of the list since it is quite big, right? and yet it's not listed at all :(

Comment: @fadden is a Googler, one well versed in these areas. If he says it should show up, and it does not show up, that suggests a possible bug. Create a test project that demonstrates the bug, then attach it along with a step-by-step explanation to an issue on http://b.android.com, so it can be investigated sometime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the exact problem was. I tried the same code in a different class and it worked fine there.